# Rails Redirecting to Wrong Path (despite `redirect_to`) only on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple `create` method that I have altered to redirect to my home page (it's for a contact us form and I want them redirected home, not to the `show` page for their message).

Here's the controller logic:

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        AdminMailer.contact_message(@contact).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to home_index_path, notice: "Thank you for reaching out!  I'll get back to you as soon as possible." }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

It functions correctly on `localhost` but for some reason it goes to `/contacts` on Heroku...which doesn't exist and throws an error.

I have checked on Heroku using bash and the controller is correctly pushed through git and is being used on the Heroku page.

What am I not seeing?  It works perfectly on `localhost`!  Why is it different on the production server?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Here's the form for the new contact:

```
<%= simple_form_for(contact) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your Name *" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your Email *" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mb-md-0">
            <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your Phone Number *" %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
            <%= f.text_area :message, class: "form-control", style: "height: 150px", placeholder: "Your Message *" %>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Send Message", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

It's in a partial that is called like this:

```
<%= render partial: "contacts/form", locals: { contact: Contact.new } %>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's redirecting? sounds like it's doing a GET request to the `/contacts` path instead of a POST request (the `create` path is usually the same as the `index` path just changing the request method). You can check the network tab in Dev Tools in your browser. Do you have any error in the browser console? can you show the form code too?

Comment: If you run the app in production mode locally does it work?  What is happening exactly in that mailer method?

Comment: @arieljuod That is correct.  It is doing a GET request and I have no idea why!  There are no errors other than the 500 error for the `index` page which doesn't exist (intentionally).  I added the form to the OP.

Comment: You can try adding a `method: :post` like `simple_form_for(contact, method: :post) do ...` to make sure it uses a POST method. Rails tries to infere the http method to use depending on the object you pass but I'm not sure what simple_form does.

Comment: Can you share the server logs?